# Neatly dealing with unparameterized List?

Tags: java

I'm working on a project using Web3j's code generator, which creates the following code:

```
public RemoteFunctionCall<List> getKeysByPurpose(BigInteger _purpose) {
        final Function function = new Function(FUNC_GETKEYSBYPURPOSE, 
                Arrays.<Type>asList(new org.web3j.abi.datatypes.generated.Uint256(_purpose)), 
                Arrays.<TypeReference<?>>asList(new TypeReference<DynamicArray<Bytes32>>() {}));
        return new RemoteFunctionCall<List>(function,
                new Callable<List>() {
                    @Override
                    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                    public List call() throws Exception {
                        List<Type> result = (List<Type>) executeCallSingleValueReturn(function, List.class);
                        return convertToNative(result);
                    }
                });
    }
```

It's a bit of a mess, but since it's generated I can't alter it. The list it returns is unparameterized, but I do know its type (and it's `byte[]`). Is there a neat way of handling this return value in my own code, where I'll need to rely on its contents' actual type, or should I just suppress the warnings?

Comment: you are just going to have to cast the result and use the appropriate SuppressWarnings.

Comment: *Completely unrelated: I appreciate the correct usage of apostrophes.*

Comment: Is your problem description related to the code you’ve posted? I see an unchecked cast to `List<Type>` in this code but since there’s also the expression `Arrays.<Type>asList(new org.web3j.abi.datatypes.generated.Uint256(_purpose))`, it’s impossible that `Type` is `byte[]`, as that would imply that `new org.web3j.abi.datatypes.generated.Uint256(_purpose)` is assignable to `byte[]`.

Comment: @Holger The code you highlighted isn't the return value, of `getKeyByPurpose`, that comes from the call to `convertToNative` which takes in `new TypeReference<DynamicArray<Bytes32>>` and results in a `byte[]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s possible to handle this without any `SuppressWarnings` annotations:

```
List<?> keys = (List<?>) getKeysByPurpose(purpose).send();

for (Object key : keys) {
    byte[] keyBytes = (byte[]) key;
    // ...
}
```